# The command electron-installer-windows --src dist/app-win32-x64/ --dest dist/installers/ does not finish execution

Tags: angular, npm, electron, electron-packager

## #Angular + Electron + electron-installer-windows + electron-packager

I have angular project from which I want to generate a windows package that can be installed by users.
After having followed all the guide in [electron-installer-windows](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-installer-windows), I cannot get the process done.
What could have gone wrong?

The **first command runs fine** but the second one hangs without any error. Just stating *Creating package (this may take a while)*

```
angularApp$electron-packager . app --platform win32 --arch x64 --out dist/
angularApp$electron-installer-windows --src dist/app-win32-x64/ --dest dist/installers/
angularApp$ng v
Angular CLI: 11.0.4
Node: 14.15.1
OS: linux x64


Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.901.12
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.901.12
@angular-devkit/core            9.1.12
@angular-devkit/schematics      11.0.4
@angular/cdk                    9.2.4
@angular/cli                    11.0.4
@angular/flex-layout            9.0.0-beta.31
@angular/material               9.2.4
@schematics/angular             11.0.4
@schematics/update              0.1100.4
rxjs                            6.5.5
typescript                      3.8.3
```

Comment: Did you found a solution have the same issue.